# What is the probability of two telephone numbers having 666 in them.

Tags: probability

My girlfriend and I both have phone numbers that are 10 digits long. They both happen to have three consecutive sixes in them (at different spots). We take it as a sign that we're meant for each other.

What is the probability that this actually occurs, if we can use digits 0-9. Is this reasoning correct?:

There are seven spots for the sixes to be placed:

---

The probability of placing the six in the first spot is $$\frac{1}{10}$$. Then the other two sixes need to be placed in the following spots, so the probability that this occuring, where the six is placed first is $$\frac{1}{10^3}$$

This can occur in seven more ways, so the total probability is $$\frac{7}{10^3}$$

Is that correct?

Comment: Note that $1+7=8$. But you are overcounting in this way. Above all the strings containing 6666 are counted at least twice. See the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $D_n$ the set of decimal strings of length $n$. We are told to compute the probability $p$ that a random string from $D_{10}$ contains the substring $s_*:=666$. In order to avoid all sorts of inclusion-exclusion-traumata we argue as follows: Let

$a_n:\quad$the number of $s\in D_n$ *not* containing $s_*$, and *not* ending with $6$,

$b_n:\quad$the number of $s\in D_n$ *not* containing $s_*$,  and ending with a *single* $6$,

$c_n:\quad$the number of $s\in D_n$ *not* containing $s_*$, and  ending with $66$,

$d_n:\quad$the number of $s\in D_n$  containing $s_*$.

One easily sees that
$$a_3=900,\quad b_3=90,\quad c_3=9,\quad d_3=1\ .$$
The $a_n$, $b_n$, $c_n$, $d_n$ satisfy the following recursion:
$$\left[\matrix{a_{n+1}\cr b_{n+1}\cr c_{n+1}\cr d_{n+1}\cr}\right]=
\left[\matrix{9&9&9&0\cr 1&0&0&0\cr 0&1&0&0\cr 0&0&1&10\cr}\right]\ \left[\matrix{a_n\cr b_n\cr c_n\cr d_n\cr}\right]\ .$$
We therefore compute $$A^7\left[\matrix{900\cr 90\cr 9\cr 1\cr}\right]=(8942446170, 895052349, 89586081, 72915400)'$$and read off $d_{10}=72\,915\,400$. It follows that
$$p={d_{10}\over 10^{10}}\doteq0.00729\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only add the probabilities if the events are disjoint, which they aren't here.  One way you can see that this reasoning is incorrect is to pretend you have a phone number with $n$ digits, which would seemingly make the answer $n / 10^3$.  But this clearly cannot be when $n > 10^3$.

You also seem to be counting the case where the trailing three digits are sixes multiple times.  I'm assuming we have a phone number with seven digits, which means there are only five *positions* for the three consecutive sixes.

The direct approach to finding this probability would be to apply the [inclusion exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to $P(\cup_{i=1}^{5} \{ \text{digits $i$ to $i + 2$ are a $6$} \})$, although this looks a bit tedious.  Maybe someone else knows of a clever method.

Answer (score 0):

We are going to count various types of five digit strings first. I write $x$ for an arbitrary decimal digit and $\dagger$ for a non-$6$ digit. The five digit strings *not* containing the substring $666$ can be put into three classes as follows:

$$C_0:\quad x\,x\,x\,x\,\dagger\>,\qquad C_1:\quad x\,x\,x\dagger6\>,\qquad C_2:\quad x\,x\dagger6\,6\ .$$
Denote by $a_i$ the number of strings  *not* containing the substring $666$ in each of these classes. Then
$$a_0=9(10^4-19)=89829,\qquad a_1=9(10^3-1)=8991,\qquad a_2=9\cdot10^2=900\ .$$
The number $a_*$ of five digit strings containing the substring $666$ therefore comes to
$$a_*=10^5-(a_0+a_1+a_2)=280\ .$$
A ten digit string is the concatenation of two five digit strings. The total number $d_{10}$ of ten digit strings containing the substring $666$ can now be computed as follows:
$$d_{10}=2\cdot a_*\cdot 10^5-a_*^2+2\cdot a_1\cdot a_2+a_2\cdot a_2=72\,915\,400\ .$$
The probability $p$ that a random ten digit phone number contains the string substring $666$ is therefore given by
$$p={d_{10}\over 10^{10}}=0.00729\ .$$

Answer (score -1):

Are you willing to accept, say, ABC-DEF-6666, that is are you counting FOUR sixes in a row as **included** in three sixes?  If so then, yes, this is correct.